# Как из VBScript определить его собственное местоположение?

Tags: vbscript

Есть скрипт vbs, как "он" может узнать путь к самому себе?

Comment: Спасибо всем:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set F = FSO.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName)

path = FSO.GetParentFolderName(F)
```

Comment: Если несложно, скажите пожалуйста, а свое имя(т.е. просто имя файла) надо отсюда вытаскивать или тоже есть функция?

Answer (score 3):

1. `WScript.Echo WScript.ScriptFullName` - возвращает полный путь к скрипту.
2. `Wscript.Echo WScript.ScriptName` - возвращает название выполненного скрипта.

Answer (score 1):

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objUser = GetObject _ 
    ("LDAP://cn=myerken,ou=management,dc=fabrikam,dc=com")

Wscript.Echo "Profile Path: " & objUser.ProfilePath 
Wscript.Echo "Script Path: " & objUser.ScriptPath 
Wscript.Echo "Home Directory: " & objUser.HomeDirectory 
Wscript.Echo "Home Drive: " & objUser.HomeDrive
```

Answer (score 0):

Сохраняет местоположение в файл
`Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`
`Set F = FSO.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName)`
`path = FSO.GetParentFolderName(F)`
`Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`
`Set tf = fso.CreateTextFile("dir.txt", True)`
`tf.WriteLine path`